npm install optional dependency hanging on WS2L - works second time
Interesting problem with npm stalling, then running again the second time on dev Windows/WSL2 Ubuntu machine.
Windows 10, WSL2 running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. No proxy or additional firewalls on network.

nvm: 0.40.1
Node: 22.11.0
npm: 10.9.0

package.json (part of it)
"devDependencies": {
  "react-email": "3.0.2"
}

then install
# will reliably fail each time if I do this
npm cache clean --force

# will fail the first time
# then work if I run it again
npm install --verbose


will sit like this for 6 hours, then continue or Ctrl C out, then:

run again and it works.
Am a beginner at node and npm.

Please run npm config command and see if TMP variable is set to a single path.
npm config ls -l 

Check the values of TMP, TMPDIR and TEMP environment variables and ensure they are set to a single path.
This may be related to the issue discussed in this thread.

Thank you - I'm on Ubuntu and running this gets no tmp path settings, so npm is going to the default of /tmp which I think is working well
